# GoでIntefaceの実装を返り値とする場合の実装できなかったパターンって何を返せばいいのでしょうか?

Tags: go

以下のようなコードを作りたいと思っています
?の部分をどうすればいいのか詰まっています。

```
type Image interface {
    Resize(width, height uint) error
}

type Png {
}

func(Png) Resize(width, height uint) error {
    //略
}

func New() (Image, error) {
    if err := hoge(); err != nil {
        return ?, err
    }
    return &Png{}, nil
}
```

実際にコードを書いていて詰まった際のプルリク
https://github.com/mafuyuk/imageresize/pull/1/files#diff-da07f373046a0a24e67b18699dc15a70R16

Comment: `nil` では不都合でしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu  nilでコンパイルエラーになっていたと思っていたのでどうしようか迷っていたのですが今確認すると通りました:bow:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単にエラー時の無意味な値を返したいのであれば、`nil` で良いように見えます。